# Changing and setting the Legend (LineGraph) Future of DynamicDataDisplay

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I'm using this great library https://d3future.codeplex.com/ to plot some 2D graphs.

In the old D3 I used to set the legend this way:

```
graf = plotter.AddLineGraph(new CompositeDataSource(xSrc, plot),
                     new Pen(brush, 4),
                     new PenDescription("myText" ));
```

But I have no idea how to obtain the same in *future D3*. Could someone make me see the light?

Exploring the **source code** I find this but can't understand how to access and change the default string "LineGraph":

```
    public class LineGraph : PointsGraphBase
        {
            static LineGraph()
            {
                Type thisType = typeof(LineGraph);

                Legend.DescriptionProperty.OverrideMetadata(thisType, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("LineGraph"));
                Legend.LegendItemsBuilderProperty.OverrideMetadata(thisType, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new LegendItemsBuilder(DefaultLegendItemsBuilder)));
            }
//more stuff

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945965/changing-legend-in-the-future-of-dynamic-data-display-wpf

Comment: @xmedeko this question was asked 2 years before

Answer (score 3):

**v0.4.0** uses the following syntax:

```
// For access to the Legend class
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts;

... snip ...
LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph(dataSource);
lineGraph.LinePen = new Pen(Brushed.Green, 1.0);
Legend.SetDescription(lineGraph, "The line label");
plotter.Children.Add(lineGraph);
... snip ...
```

**v0.3.0** used the following syntax:

```
plotter.AddLineGraph(dataSource, pen, marker, new PenDescription("The line label"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add line graph to the plotter (`AddLineGraph(...)`), one of the parameters is description string.

Answer (score 0):

WGW is Spot On! Thumbs Up from me.

I found that doing it a slightly different way was easier to understand:

```
<Page 

...

xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"

... >

... 

<Grid Name="GridOne" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="13" />

</Page>
```

And the Code Behind:

```
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts;

...

ChartPlotter PlotterOne = new ChartPlotter();

// Add a Graph to One:
GridOne.Children.Add(PlotterOne);

LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
line.ProvideVisiblePoints = true;
line.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
line.StrokeThickness = 1;
line.DataSource = GetDayDataSource();

Legend.SetDescription(line, "Today's Activity");

PlotterOne.Children.Add(line);
```

Hope this helps.